# How can I remove responses from LiveHTTPHeaders output using awk, perl or sed?

Tags: linux, perl, firefox, awk

Let's say I have something like this (this is only an example, actual request will be different: I loaded StackOverflow with LiveHTTPHeaders enabled to have some samples to work on):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070220 Firefox/2.0.0.2
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Sat, 28 Nov 2009 16:04:24 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2009 16:04:23 GMT
Content-Length: 19015
----------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Full log of requests and responses is available on [pastebin](http://pastebin.org/58143)

And I want to remove all responses (HTTP/1.x 200 OK and everything in that response, for example) and all one liners showing page address. I would like to only have all **requests** left in text file with saved LiveHTTPHeaders output.

So, the output would be:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070220 Firefox/2.0.0.2
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive

GET /so/all.css?v=5290 HTTP/1.1
Host: sstatic.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070220 Firefox/2.0.0.2
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/

...
```

Again, the full text of what I want to keep is available on [pastebin](http://pastebin.org/58144).

If I save LiveHTTPHeaders captured session to text file and I would like to get result like from second 'code' in this question, how do I do this? Maybe with `awk`, `sed` or `perl`? Or something else? I'm on Linux.

---

Edit:
I'm trying to run Sinan's script. Script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
local $/ = "\n\n";
while (<>) {
    print if /^GET|POST/; # Add more request types as needed
}
```

I tried running it this way:

```
./cleanup-headers.pl livehttp.txt > filtered.txt
```

And this way:

```
perl cleanup-headers.pl < livehttp.txt > filtered.txt
```

... file filtered.txt was created but it's totally empty.

**Anyone tried it on FULL headers i pasted into pastebin? Did it worked?**

[Full headers](http://pastebin.org/58143)

Comment: Please resubmit with relevant text in the post, well-formatted. Also, your question is very hard to understand. What is your programming problem?

Comment: I can't submit code in post because stackoverflow thinks i want to post spam links ;). I'm trying to convert output i have in pastebin1 to what i have in pastebin2 - is it more understandable this way or i should explain more?

Comment: ...I want to remove parts of pastebin1 to get what's in pastebin2. I want to remove useless (for my task) information that tool (livehttpheaders) is generating. You can compare headers in pastebin links to see differences.

Comment: So, what *code* have you written to accomplish this task, and which part of *programming* this task is giving you trouble?

Comment: Jonathan Feinberg: Me? I tried to write it in awk but couldn't achieve anything. Text transformations aren't my best side... and no, I don't claim I'm programming guru or anything. I'm hobbyist and there are many things I'm weak at. On the other hand, if you don't understand what's programming related in this question... well, lol. Reading headers and seeing differences between them in these two examples is so hard for you? I even shortened second one to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Tim: No need to get snippy. Please see the edited post for a better way to present the information. Help people help you by helping them see more easily what they need to see to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why before it didn't let me post claiming I'm posting (spam) links...

Comment: I also don't think "do this for me" is what SO is for.

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg: While I agree with you in spirit, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26876/is-this-question-really-a-real-question

Comment: To this: "Anyone tried it on FULL headers i pasted into pastebin? Did it worked?" Yup, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're having trailing whitespace issues.

```
$ sed -e 's/^\s*$//' livehttp.txt | \
  perl -e '$/ = ""; while (<>) { print if /^(GET|POST)/ }'
```

This works by putting Perl's readline operator into paragraph mode (via `$/ = ""`), which grabs records a chunk at a time, separated by two or more consecutive newlines.

It's nice when it works, but it's a bit brittle. Blank but not empty lines will gum up the works, but `sed` can clean those up.

Equivalent and more concise command:

```
$ sed -e 's/^\s*$//' livehttp.txt | perl -000 -ne 'print if /^(GET|POST)/'
```

Answer (score 5):

In Perl:

```
local $/ = "\n\n";
while (<>) {
    print if /^(?:GET|POST)/; # Add more request types as needed
}
```

**Notes:** Looking at the output generated by LiveHTTPHeaders, entries are quite clearly separated by two newlines, so I think setting `$/ = "\n\n"` is more appropriate than setting `$/ = ''`. I believe your problems were due to the fact that the lines in your input file were actually indented.

I did originally download the file from *pastebin* and use the full file to test my script. I do not believe the file you were using to test on your computer was identical to the one you put on *pastebin*.

If you want to robustly deal with possibly indented lines while remaining consistent with the format of the output of LiveHTTPHeaders, you should use something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

local $/ = "\n\n";
while (<>) {
    next unless /^\s*(?:GET|POST)/;
    s!^\s+!!gm;
    print;
}
```

I consider using `sed` and `perl` in the same pipeline to be a little bit of an abomination.

Comment: That's really clever idea of accomplishing this, I wouldn't think about it :). Thanks a lot, I'll try it!

Comment: ...but this prints whole section or just one line that has get or post in it?

Comment: ./test.pl > livehttp.txt

and then it starts to work, won't end (i don't get console free back) and when i look into file all contents are deleted :(

Comment: @Tim The output file cannot be the same as the input file: `./test.pl input.log > filtered.log`. There is nothing in the program that overwrites anything. The program outputs one request section at a time.

Comment: ./cleanup-headers.pl livehttp.txt > filtered.txt and filtered.txt is created by this and is empty file... i seriously don't know what's wrong here

Comment: @Tim post the exact contents of the script you are running in **your question** as well as the exact command line by copying and pasting, not retyping.

Comment: ...are you sure your code is correct? It only creates empty file or removes file content depending on how it's run.

Comment: Assigning the empty string to `$/` puts `<>` in paragraph mode.

Comment: You also need parens to have GET and POST share the anchor: `perl -le 'print "Match" if "foo POST" =~ /^GET|POST/'`

Answer (score 0):

Run Sinan's code as:

```
perl test.pl < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Same - filtered.txt is totally empty. Now i feel dumb, I can't even run script :/

Comment: Anyone tried it on FULL headers i pasted into pastebin? Did it worked?

Comment: There's no difference between the two. From the "I/O Operators
 section of perlop: "The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of `sed` and `awk`. Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line."

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators

Answer (score 0):

just one gawk command

```
awk -vRS= '/^(GET|POST)/' ORS="\n\n" file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bash shell

```
while read -r line
do    
    case "$line" in
        GET*|POST*) flag=1;;        
        "") flag=0;;
    esac
    [ "$flag" -eq 1 ] && echo "$line"
done < "file"
```